# How to make a better impression in an interview?

Tags: interviewing, career-development

A friend of mine has difficulties to land their first job as a software engineer. He does well on technical interviews, phone interviews, but still hasn't received an offer.

I have been wondering if his ethnicity might be the reason, or if he is doing something in the interview that comes across as "not likable".  How can he figure out what is happening at the interview stage that's causing him to not get the job?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the Workplace. Unfortunately, we cannot guess why he is getting rejected. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking because it is not clear how we can help.

Comment: Voting to close.  There are many variables that determine whether someone gets a job and we don't know your friend well enough to offer any real help and if we did it would be very specific to your friend.

Comment: I made a fairly substantial edit to make this question on-topic (and what people were implicitly answering).  This might now be a duplicate, but I didn't find it.  I've reopened, so if it *is* a dupe the community can mark it as such.

Comment: Question title doesn't match question content.

Comment: Please add a country tag as well. "Ethnicity" (or, what do you call it, ethnic discrimination?) is not a universal issue.

Comment: You don't have any facts to present except that he didn't get the job. And you are speculating all over the map as to the reason. We can't tell why he wasn't successful from your narrative, We are not set up to speculate. Voting to close. Without hard facts, it's impossible to conclude anything.

Comment: Ask the companies if they can provide you a contact of the interviewer (It's hard to get) or try to get in touch with them personally to know if they can help to know your flaws.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to a recruiter. They have an incentive to place people. Since they are not directly doing the hiring, your friend may get a little more honest feedback on what she may be doing wrong.

It's not ideal. I wouldn't expect to get a job. Be sincere about wanting to get placed and you may get the help you need.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The question will probably be closed because we cannot guess what his problem his, and thus we cannot help solving it.

However, when your friend gets rejected, he could ask something like :

*"Dear Sir/Madam,
I understand that my application has been declined. As I am striving towards self-improvement, would you please explain me what went wrong in this interview ?"*

Not everyone will answer, but some people will give him their feedback.

Comment: With the question in it's current state and the core component being "How can he figure out what is happening at the interview stage that's causing him to not get the job?", this is definitely the best answer - ask the people who are not giving him a job why they didn't give him a job!